# How to parse a Http request that contain a csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to handle a request that contains a csv file in the body . Exist any library in python3 that extract or parse the http request and grab the csv file. I'm a beginner in python.

**My request**

```
file = {'file': open('../file/10.csv', 'rb')}
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/function/preprocess', files=file)
print(response.content)
```

**My handler**

```
def handle(event, context):
return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": event.body
}
```

**Postman**

```
---------------------------157082355573515401018537
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="10.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
id,vendor_id,pickup_datetime,dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,pickup_longitude,pickup_latitude,dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude,store_and_fwd_flag,trip_duration
id2875421,2,2016-03-14 17:24:55,2016-03-14 17:32:30,1,-73.982154846191406,40.767936706542969,-73.964630126953125,40.765602111816406,N,455
----------------------------157082355573515401018537--
```